# Webpack dist: index.html is a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I'm pretty new to Webpack, and have followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-custom-login) to add authentication to a React app I have been working on.

It all works fine in development, however I get a blank page when trying to run the distribution files.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs      = require('fs');
const path    = require('path'),
      join    = path.join,
      resolve = path.resolve;

const getConfig = require('hjs-webpack');

const isDev  = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isTest = NODE_ENV === 'test';

const root    = resolve(__dirname);
const src     = join(root, 'src');
const modules = join(root, 'node_modules');
const dest    = join(root, 'dist');

var config = getConfig({
  isDev: isDev,
  in: join(src, 'app.js'),
  out: dest,
  html: function (context) {
    return {
      'index.html': context.defaultTemplate({
        title: 'My Title',
        publicPath: isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000/' : 'http://localhost:9000/',
        meta: {
          'name': 'My name',
          'description': 'My desc'
        }
      })
    }
  }
});

// ENV variables
const dotEnvVars = dotenv.config();
const environmentEnv = dotenv.config({
  path: join(root, 'config', `${NODE_ENV}.config.js`),
  silent: true,
});
const envVariables =
    Object.assign({}, dotEnvVars, environmentEnv);

const defines =
  Object.keys(envVariables)
  .reduce((memo, key) => {
    const val = JSON.stringify(envVariables[key]);
    memo[`__${key.toUpperCase()}__`] = val;
    return memo;
  }, {
    __NODE_ENV__: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
  });

config.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(defines)
].concat(config.plugins);
// END ENV variables

// CSS modules
const cssModulesNames = `${isDev ? '[path][name]__[local]__' : ''}[hash:base64:5]`;

const matchCssLoaders = /(^|!)(css-loader)($|!)/;

const findLoader = (loaders, match) => {
  const found = loaders.filter(l => l && l.loader && l.loader.match(match))
  return found ? found[0] : null;
}
// existing css loader
const cssloader =
  findLoader(config.module.loaders, matchCssLoaders);

const newloader = Object.assign({}, cssloader, {
  test: /\.module\.css$/,
  include: [src],
  loader: cssloader.loader.replace(matchCssLoaders, `$1$2?modules&localIdentName=${cssModulesNames}$3`)
})
config.module.loaders.push(newloader);
cssloader.test = new RegExp(`^(?!.*(module|bootstrap)).*${cssloader.test.source}`)
cssloader.loader = newloader.loader

config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /bootstrap\.css$/,
  include: [modules],
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
})

// postcss
config.postcss = [].concat([
  require('precss')({}),
  require('autoprefixer')({}),
  require('cssnano')({})
])
// END postcss

// Roots
config.resolve.root = [src, modules]
config.resolve.alias = {
  'css': join(src, 'styles'),
  'containers': join(src, 'containers'),
  'components': join(src, 'components'),
  'utils': join(src, 'utils'),

  'styles': join(src, 'styles')
}
// end Roots

// Testing
if (isTest) {
  config.externals = {
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
  }
  config.module.noParse = /[/\\]sinon\.js/;
  config.resolve.alias['sinon'] = 'sinon/pkg/sinon';

  config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(p => {
    const name = p.constructor.toString();
    const fnName = name.match(/^function (.*)\((.*\))/)

    const idx = [
      'DedupePlugin',
      'UglifyJsPlugin'
    ].indexOf(fnName[1]);
    return idx < 0;
  })
}
// End Testing

module.exports = config;
```

I am serving the files using express using this script:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var path = require('path');

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9000!')
})
```

All I get is a blank page with this markup:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>My title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:9000/stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost:9000/javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Not sure what I'm missing, there doesn't seem to be any JS executing at all, and I'm not sure how to go about debugging minified JS...

Any help or pointers would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you screenshot the console?

Comment: Sure, does this help?
https://monosnap.com/file/TmwjO6KY9EN6bPPBqdr09H7ByR7Tqr

Comment: I mean the dev tools console in the browser; sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Yes apologies, I have edited the comment above. https://monosnap.com/file/TmwjO6KY9EN6bPPBqdr09H7ByR7Tqr
It seems both my CSS and JS are being replaced with HTML markup somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your express server isn't configured to serve static files (other than the html). Add the `express.static` middleware before the wildcard route.

Comment: @jcbmb remember to accept an answer so other people know it's solved (also, I get points!).